# Admin port with Dropwizard metrics not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, metrics, dropwizard

I'm following the DropWizard "[Getting Started](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/)" tutorial and while I got everything else working the 8081 admin port is blank and clicking on any of the hyperlinks to the metrics resource, threads resource, and health check resource is giving me a 101 error. Can't figure out why I followed it pretty much verbatim. 
Here's my POM if that helps:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>DropWizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>DropWizard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldService</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, there are a couple of things to note:

1) If you specify the dropwizard dependency you do not need to specify the metrics dependencies.

2) The 8081 port, for whatever reason, was not cooperating. When I changed the admin port to 9091 everything worked as expected. If you want to change the ports then specify the following in your admin file:

```
http:
    port: 9090
    adminPort: 9091
```

I assume you can use whatever ports you like, these happened to work when I used them. When specifying the ports there must be a tab in between http and the information that comes afterwards. Hopefully this helps others avoid the hair-pulling frustration I encountered

Comment: I am pulling my hair out.  The above worked on 0.6.2, but now on 0.7.0 I get errors about 'unrecognized field http'.  Also the port 8081 problem, if like me, is on Windows and McAfee is using that port and not an easy task to change that, so I am still fighting this on 0.7.0.

Comment: I haven't touched DropWizard in 6 months but I remember it being very particular about that sort of thing. Make sure you don't have any trailing whitespace or anything of that sort. There is also a dropwizard google group where you can ask for help:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dropwizard-user

Comment: Finally got is solved - using the docs from 0.7.0 - the configuration format is being changed as part of 0.7.0, so using the new format it now works! Just wanted to get the mention of the adminPort because it was very frustrating that their 'Getting Started' wouldn't start on Windows.  So those of you reading this - check the new docs for 0.7.0 (and beyond) for the correct format because the format above does NOT and will not work for 0.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropwizard admin interface (as of 0.6.2) is only compatible with Metrics 2.*. Dropwizard 0.7.0 will work with Metrics 3 once it's released.

Comment: So how do I get it to work then? I looked up the Metrics release notes and changed the versions for each metrics dependency to 2.2.0 (the last before 3.0.0) and got this error:

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project DropWizard: Could not resolve dependencies for project DropWizard:DropWizard:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0, com.codahale.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:2.2.0: Failure to find com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]